# Whats the fault in the reasoning behind the number of streamlines possibility?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vector-fields

Consider a fluid which is moving from a pipe which is having area of cross section A1 and one point in space and in other its A2 area A1<A2 , we say that can visualize the flow by making streamlines from that one space to other space , consider the cross section to be both of circular sections , now my question is we know therr a infinie points on a circle so that means from A1 area we can make infinite streamlines called this as N1 (total streamlines) , now from A2 area though there are infinite points we can consider so there too infinite stream lines call this N2 , now we can observe that points we can select on bigger area would be more than small area , so doesnt this means streamlines from A2 will be different in numbers as compared to A1 cross section area ? Where is the fault ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The streamlines will become "denser" in a smaller pipe, where the "density" of the streamlines corresponds to mass flow rate, $\rho\mathbf{v}$. Evidently, by your reasoning, the flow rate $\rho\mathbf{v}$ must scale inversely to cross-sectional area of the pipe (assuming uniform flow).

Comment: So consider we draw all the streamlines from the dense region , that means in the bigger area the distance between streamlines will have some gaps left out (some portion of area being empty with streamlines) , what does that means? If there exists gap then that means there fluid is not flowing ehich doesnt makes sense .

Comment: We treat the fluid as a continuous medium, so we can't really think about drawing *all* the streamlines. Rather, we draw streamlines to help us visualize the flow, with the density of streamlines corresponding loosely to the flow rate of the fluid.

Comment: The streamlines aren't meant to be taken literally as the only trajectories that particles in the fluid can follow.

Comment: Understood thanks Daniel